# when I try to copy text from the command line strange characters appear

Tags: command-line, 16.04, mate

when I try to copy text from the command line strange characters appear.

I have never not been able to copy and paste in the virtual terminals. 
I tried installing GPM just in-case, but it did not help the issue.

Here I tried to copy the alphabet, but got G2#b2.... etc.

what is this non-sense?

My OS is Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and the terminals are mate-terminal.

[image]